# BufferedImage duplicate border

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am trying to duplicate the border pixel n number of times. I have managed to do it for part of the top border, but am struggling with the rest. Is there an easier way to do this, as it seem overly complex for what I am trying to achieve.

```
public BlurredImage(int n) {

    try {
        castle = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("test.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("cannot read image");
    }

    int w = (2*n)+castle.getWidth();
    int h = (2*n)+castle.getHeight();

    int origW =castle.getWidth();
    int origH = castle.getHeight();
    System.out.println(w);
    System.out.println(h);
    BufferedImage enlargedImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, castle.getType());

    //Map existing image
    for (int y=0; y < origH; y++){
        for (int x=0; x < origW; x++){
            enlargedImage.setRGB(x+n, y+n, castle.getRGB(x, y));
        }
    }

    //Top border
    for (int y=0; y < n; y++){
        for (int x=0; x < origW; x++){
            enlargedImage.setRGB(x+n, y, castle.getRGB(x, 0));
        }
    }

    //Bottom border
    for (int y=0; y > y+n; y++){
        for (int x=0; x < origW; x++){
            enlargedImage.setRGB(x+n, y, castle.getRGB(x, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't enlarging the image, incidentally - just shifting it by `n` pixels...Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? What do you mean by "duplicate the border pixel"? A proper [SCCEE](http://sscce.org) that we can actually run, rather than partial code would make it easier for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your bottom border is the for-loop for the y value and the .setRGB. Your .setRGB appears to be a copy/paste of the top border, and is getting/setting the same pixel as the top border code.  I changed your code slightly:  The y for-loop now iterates over the number of border copies you want, and the setRGB/getRGB reference the correct positions in the images

```
//Bottom border
for (int y = 0; y < n; y++){
    for (int x = 0; x < origW; x++){
        enlargedImage.setRGB(x + n, h - 1 - y, castle.getRGB(x, origH - 1));
    }
}
```